# Perfect pinhole diffraction pattern with sharp fringes using a 632nm laser

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, diffraction

I'm trying to produce a diffraction pattern with pinhole using a laser of 632nm wavelength .The pinholes' diameter are ranging from 10um , 25um , 50 um , 0.1mm and so on .
I also have good lenses for collimation and focusing.

What is of importance to me is to generate distinguishable bands in a way that I can make sure there exist no photons in dark band and the fringes are perfect borders between light and dark bands.

At the moment what I can observe is such a pattern .
http://www.pictureshoster.com/files/ihyxqb9relj0tv9mbab6.png

You can also have a look at setup which I used .
http://www.pictureshoster.com/files/y0iqmqttzzc4y8n2y6mq.jpg

As you see there aren't perfect circles over there and borders have some aberrations!
Is there any way to produce sharp fringes of diffraction pattern ?

Comment: do you have slits or pinholes? I can't see how you get circles with your setup. I'm guessing you have pinholes and what we see in the first photo is an ideal (Airy function) diffraction pattern - right? So you've got the camera gain up high so that you can see the outer details of the field - the central peak and first sidelobe is saturating the camera? Is this right? Moreover, I wouldn't say there is an aberration problem - there seems more to be a multiple reflexion problem (the high spatial frequency interference pattern over the main one is what is bothering you?)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance  Actually you are right it was a mistake by me . All the **slits** which I mentioned already I meant **pinholes** and iris **diaphragms**. I also corrected the setup which I drew before . I will double check with the saturation of camera again . It's nice idea .  I'm not sure if I got your final comment in paranthesis!  You think is it possible to have a perfect circle over there so I make sure that with a precision of several microns I have a dark and light band border ?

Comment: Developing this diffraction pattern , my main idea is basically producing a **distinguishable border for dark and light area which is fully customizable to fit it on to an area in micron dimensions**. Then I make sure that from zero to 2 microns I have illuminated area and from 2 to 4 it would be no photons there to illuminate .
All in all in this way I ask for any other kind of setup or utilizing diffraction pattern which I'm already working on .

Comment: you seem to asking for a step function in the image intensity.  This is impossible with real instruments as some aberrations and scattered light will cause imperfections.  Also as seen below the intensity pattern is a Bessel function.  As far as I know this goes to zero smoothly and then only for a moment.

Comment: @Nic So you think there exist no way that I can at least achieve this goal with a good approximation (With lowest imperfections and using normal optical instruments) ?
In my opinion going beyond the usual dimensions and facilities can help .This is of course **real** but not in hand and with **usual** instruments .
Generating a mask with absorptive and transmittive layers.
Using a microscope and scanning in microns, I can make sure that I have a well distinguishable step function in the image intensity with less than 3 microns in length of confusion . Any ideas ?

Comment: I think no, diffraction at edges will always cause image degradation to the extent of blurring the image

Answer (score 2):

This image is the Fraunhofer (farfield) diffraction pattern from a circular aperture. I have labeled the main problems I see in it below.

[image]

In the middle, the image is saturating, i.e. the camera's gain is too high. I suggest the first thing you need to do if you haven't already is to find a freeware software to convert the camera image into a 2D field of intensities. Many cameras are quite linear, so that the greylevel brightness for each pixel is pretty much proportional to the light's intensity. Once you have the image intensities, you can readily see saturation (peaks crashing into the maximum intensity) and other nonideal effects and use this knowledge to tune your measurement.

I would suggest the high frequency ripples you are seeing are extremely small and you're unlikely to get rid of them. I take it that these ripples are what you mean by "aberration". When you lower the camera's gain so that the central peak is not saturating, these ripples will be very tiny indeed. Although they may seem worrying, try taking a cross-section through them with your image analysis software and you'll see that their amplitude is very small compared to the main lobe intensity. The human eye and site system is exquisitely sensitive to patterns like this, so interference like this is wont to seem much worse than it really is. These ripples I believe are coming from a point scatterer somewhere near a system Fourier plane, i.e. at or near the pinhole itself or it could be some dirt near the aperture stop of your imaging system.

Once you've got the camera's gain properly set, you should be looking for the Airy function intensity distribution discussed in section 8.5.2 of Born and Wolf "Principles of Optics". The section is called "the circular aperture". Take a cross-section through the peak and you should be looking for the following intensity distribution:

$I(r) = \left(\frac{2\,D\,J_1\left(k\,a\,\frac{r}{D}\right)}{k\,a\,r}\right)^2$

where $D$ is the distance between the pinhole and imaging plane, $r$ the radial coordinate on the imaging plane, $a$ the pinhole's radius, $k$ the freespace wavenumber of the light question and $J_1$ the first order Bessel function of the first kind. See below for symbol definition.

[image]

I have plotted below what you should theoretically be seeing; as you can see the side lobes are of very small intensity compared with the central peak. The Mathematica command I used to plot this was DensityPlot[(2 BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/ Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]. The argument on each axis was the variable $k\,a\,\frac{r}{D}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the overdrive (saturation), the imperfections you see are laser speckles. It is an interference effect produced by imperfections inside your laser, possibly involving some dust or back-reflections. If you use cheap diode lasers, you will almost always get some of these, even from just the bare laser chip.

There is a trick to clean up your beam: Focus it into a small spot and use an appropriately sized pinhole to only use the bit that corresponds to the TEM$_{00}$ mode. All the (small) imperfections will be spatially separated in the focal plane. The setup is a bit more complicated than what you have because, to be effective, you will need to use not just a suitable lens (or, more likely, multiple lenses) and one of your smaller pinholes. Because the position of the pinhole is so critical, you will need a translation stage, ideally in three axes. But the result is worth it; holographers use this trick to rid their art from similar artifacts.